# Genymotion of any device model with api 18 is not starting

Tags: android, genymotion

'm currently trying out Genymotion and boy, it's so much faster than the ADT emulator.

But I need to install Google Play to download some apps into it.
when i start nexus 7 or galaxy s4 or htc 1 with api 18 version 4.3
it does not start it only shows the starting screen
i have tried it many times for different devices only nexus 7 with version 4.1.1 runs
any one can help me because i want to use google play services on genymotion and version 4.3 is required

Comment: Try manually updating your VirtualBox installation to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

you have to install arm file into genymotion emulator simple drag and drop that zip file.

Comment: it is not starting it only shows the startup screen with name android not more than this

Comment: are you unable to start genymotion emulator ?

Comment: yes i have core i7 hp laptop which meets all the requirements but it is starting emulator but only welcome not is showing

Answer (score 0):

Try below steps:

- Uninstall Genymotion
- Uninstall Virtualbox
- Install latest Virtualbox
- Install Genymotion (the version without Virtualbox)

Then simply, drag & drop ***gapps*** zip folder into genymotion emulator and reboot emulator.

Thanks.