# Genymotion will not load a virtual device

Tags: android, virtualbox, genymotion

I have been using Genymotion for about 4months now and all was well until I updated Virtual box to 4.3 . I did not like it because I didnt know how to run 64 bit OSs on it,so i downgraded to 4.2 . Now genymotion machines wont run. at the end of every machine (factory-backup) is appended and this is the error I get:

*Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Galaxy S4 - 4.2.2 - API 17 - 1080x1920.*

Failed to open/create the internal network 'HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter' (VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND).

Failed to attach the network LUN (VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND).

Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: Console
Interface: IConsole {db7ab4ca-2a3f-4183-9243-c1208da92392}


Reinstalling genymotion or virtualbox yields no results. I am also running VMware on my machine. Please help I use this for development purposes

Comment: have you tried creating new devices?

Comment: already tried that,several times

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The following steps from an answer on the superuser community (https://superuser.com/a/1002243) worked for me. I'm running VirtualBox 5.0.10 on Windows 10, with the Fall 2015 Windows 10 update. In my case, the problem seems to be directly associated with the Windows 10 update. (I'm using VirtualBox in conjunction with Genymotion 2.6.0, but I don't think the Genymotion version is a factor.)

1. Open Windows "Network and Sharing Center"
2. Click "Change adapter settings"
3. Right click your Virtualbox host-only adapter and select Properties
4. Enable "Virtualbox NDIS6 Bridget Networking Driver" (if it's disabled - if it's not, see next)

If the checkbox in step 4 was disabled, VirtualBox should work just fine now (no reboot needed). Otherwise repeat steps 3-4 for every network adapter you have (Ethernet, WiFi...) and always uncheck the NDIS6 checkbox -> apply -> check it again -> apply.

Comment: Unbelievable... Thank you sir

Comment: Thank you so much.  That was a painful troubleshooting then found your answer and it turns out to be something so simple.

Comment: A frustrating hour lost trying to fix this problem, and this fixed it immediately.  Thanks.

Comment: I am facing same problem on mac. can any one suggest me ?

Answer (score 3):

1. Click on "***Open Network and Sharing Center***" by right clicking network icon
   [image]
2. Open channel adapter settings
3. Click on Properties of V**irtualBox Host-Only Network** by right clicking
   [image]
4. Enable **Virtualbox NDIS6 Bridget Networking Driver** by tick on box and click OK button.

[image]

5. Open your VirtualBox and try opening device. It work now.

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove the host-only network adapter in virtual box. Then reinit the vm from genymotion. The host-only network adapter will be reinstalled in virtual box and your problem should be fixed. I wish i could say this fix is perm, but occasionaly i need to repeat the exercise... unstatisfying but working :)

Comment: It should be made clear that "remove the host-only network adapter" means: in VirtualBox go to File > Preferences > Network > Host-only networks, and delete the adapter listed there. It is *not* sufficient to disable the network adapter in the network settings of the virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

Check my answer : [Genymotion Virtual device issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22419699/genymotion-of-any-device-model-with-api-18-is-not-starting/22470170#22470170)

Try manually updating your VirtualBox installation to the latest version.

Comment: this made things worse

Comment: Yes. Genymotion has a serious problem lately. Emulator can no longer be installed with google play services. It makes the emulator unusable.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to me.yay 's comment I would add to make the following changes:

Then edit the new network adapter and use the following settings:

IPv4 Address : 192.168.1.201 IPv4 network mask : 255.255.255.0

Then in the DHCP server tab: Address: 192.168.1.100 mask: 255.255.255.0 Lower address: 192.168.1.101 Upper address : 192.168.1.199

Check to see which Ethernet adapter # you have now set up - this might be important later on. Click OK for all the open boxes or save whatever you have.

Then try and run genyMotion again. This worked for me.

There is one more thing you may have to do if this still doesnt work. Go to Network and sharing centre . Change adapter settings and disable all the Ethernet connections EXCEPT for the Ethernet adapter you have just created.

Answer (score 1):

just get into virtual box open settings of your virtual device,search for network ,verify it is in host only adapter but just down are the advance settings.
click there and set the option promiscuos  mode  to allow all. and that´s it.
start to virtual machine and start from genymotion 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIqyf.png)